# Option to allow MS Excel to speak cells while I type in another application

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-to-speech

I would like to use MS Excel's "Speak cells" capability to read me the contents of some cells, so I can enter the data into another application (Google Chrome). When I click "speak cells" in excel, it works as expected, but as soon as I go to google chrome to enter the data, the speaking stops.

This post https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-speak-cells/m-p/206973 made me think it might have something to do with my dual monitors, but after placing both programs on the same screen, the problem persisted.

Has anyone else had or solved this problem?

Using Office 365 ProPlus and... any other application in Windows 10.

Comment: Are U talking about Google Sheet or doc ?

Comment: Neither. I am using MS Excel to speak the data, then entering the information into a web browser (it's a custom web application, not google sheets or docs). It doesn't really matter though - excel stops when I click any other application.

Comment: What web application you are using so far ?

Comment: The web application is an internal one for my workplace. Again, it's when I try to use *any* other application - as soon as Excel becomes the "inactive" application, it stops speaking.

Comment: Dear @Nova,, difficult to figure out the problem since is between two applications where one is unknown to me !!

Comment: @RajeshS, my point is that you could test with any other application - ms word, notepad, typing into any web browser - you don't need access to the web app to see that ms excel stops talking when you go into any other application, at least on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, this looks like a by design situation.

I tested in Office 365, Office 2016, Office 2013, and all three different versions got the same results as you did.

Every time Excel stops speaking, I click speaking again, Excel doesn't speak from scratch, it continues to speak what's next, just as I pressed the pause key.

As a workaround:

If you have a virtual or remote environment, excel doesn't stop speaking when I switch virtual to local.

Comment: OP has different issue but not what U have descried,, OP is struggling with either Google Sheet or voice recolonization using Web browser !!

Comment: My understanding is that when he uses the "speak cell" feature in Excel, switching to Google Chrome will stop speaking. My test results are the same as his.
If my understanding is wrong, please feel free to correct me

Comment: On any web browser while search with Google, Microphone icon is required,, if not U need to activate this,,, but first setup Speech Recolonization using Control Panel,, and if U or OP is thinking about Google Sheet,, it does not supports Text to Speech,, but the Google Doc does have !!

Comment: OP was in this situation when he was using the "Speak cell" in Excel....   I did reproduce the OP problem, which seems to be a By design situation.

Comment: Read OP's last comment above !!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
One hint: copy & paste your cells in outlook & use the Read Aloud feature of Outlook, it works (at least for me).
... until this gets fixed by MS.